# Change MySQL query based on <select> input to change Highcharts graph

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, xmlhttprequest

So I have 3 Bootstrap Panels on one site, each with a panel-header that contains a  input and a panel-body that contains the Highcharts graph. The  is dynamically filled with options from a database.

That's how a panel looks like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-9"><h4>Graph 1</h4></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control">
                <?php include('get_options_from_database.php'); ?>
            </select>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="highcharts-graph" style="width:100%; height:auto;"></div>
</div>
```

The get_options_from_database.php just uses a MySQL query to pull the relevant data from database and then a while loop to echo the options. Each option has a specific value (just simple integers). And based on the selected option I want to change the MySQL query that pulls the data for the Highcharts graph and redraw that. Note that the other two graphs should stay like they are unless the selected value of the select has changed. But how do I exactly do that.

So what I (think I) have to do:

1. Read the value of the selected option of the
2. Write the value into a variale and pass it over to the MySQL query (is in a separate file) which gets the data for the graph
3. Redraw the graph with the new data but without redrawing the other two

I'm not sure if it's possible to do with out refreshing the page, but as long as only the graph changes where the  has been changed I think I don't mind it. Another thing I'm unsure is if I would need a submit button that would trigger everything after selecting an option.

**EDIT:**
Ok, now the next problem. The response from the xmlhttp object seems to be in the wrong format. When I open the Chrome developer tool and take a look at for example

> getchart.php?option=1

It contains html tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        [1420068600000,21.5],[1420070400000,19.2],[1420072200000,19],[1420074000000,22.6],[1420075800000,21.3],[1420077600000,21.5],[1420079400000,19.9],[1420081200000,22.3],[1420083000000,19]
<!-- And a lot more data -->
</body>
</html>
```

But I only need the data itself, like:

```
[1420068600000,21.5],[1420070400000,19.2],[1420072200000,19],[1420074000000,22.6],[1420075800000,21.3],[1420077600000,21.5],
and so on...
```

I have tried and just pasted a cut-out of the data into the javascript for the highchart graph and it works just fine. The graph even gets automatically redrawn if I change the selection (obviously the same data every time because it's static).
So unless I'm doing something wrong I propably need a way to cut away those html tags and insert the result `data: [ here ]`

This is how it looks like when I pasted the cut-out in, which works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getData(nr)
    { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                $('#graphcontainer').highcharts('StockChart', {
                    chart: {
                        type : 'spline',
                        height: 650,
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },

                    rangeSelector : {
                        selected : 1
                    },

                    title : {
                        text : ''
                    },

                    series : [{
                        name : 'Data',
//Here is where the data goes. This is basically how 
//it must look when the response comes back but the html tags 
//make it useless (I think)
                        data :  [ [1420068600000,21.5],[1420070400000,19.2],[1420072200000,19],[1420074000000,22.6],[1420075800000,21.3],[1420077600000,21.5],[1420079400000,19.9],[1420081200000,22.3],[1420083000000,19],[1420084800000,22],[1420086600000,18],[1420088400000,18.7],[1420090200000,20.9],[1420092000000,21.2],[1420093800000,20.3],[1420095600000,18.3],[1420097400000,19.5],[1420099200000,22.6],[1420101000000,21.4],[1420102800000,21.6],[1420104600000,18.5],[1420106400000,20.8],[1420108200000,23],[1420110000000,23],[1420111800000,18.7],[1420113600000,20.4],[1420115400000,18.5],[1420117200000,19.6],[1420119000000,21.3],[1420120800000,18.6],[1420122600000,20.9],[1420124400000,18.5],[1420126200000,21.4],[1420128000000,20.8],[1420129800000,22.2],[1420131600000,19.4],[1420133400000,22.4],[1420135200000,19.4],[1420137000000,18],[1420138800000,20.9],[1420140600000,21.4],[1420142400000,18.9],[1420144200000,22.6],[1420146000000,19.4],[1420147800000,19.6],[1420149600000,21.5],[1420151400000,19.2],[1420153200000,21.6],[1420155000000,18.2], ] ,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueDecimals: 2
                        }
                    }]
                });
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","getchart.php?option="+nr,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why can't you follow tutorials? I mean [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing) -> "PREPROCESS DATA USING JSON" and [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database). I think the problem is that your data is a string, while should be JSON. `json_encode` may help you, but I think you are creating your JSON file as string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering when the user changes the options should be fairly simple:

```
option.addEventListener('change', function(){ ... });
```

Redrawing the chart without refreshing the page can be done with an XMLHTTPRequest object like so:

```
var request = new XMLHTTPRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function(){ ## do something when response comes back};
request.open("get", "example.com/getchart?option=1", true);
request.send();
```

Once the XMLHTTPRequest comes back with an answer:

```
if(request.readystate === 4){ document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML = request.responseText };
```

(Place something along those lines inside the 'onreadystatechange').
This is of course assuming that the response it gets back is formatted in HTML, just like what you are doing with 'get_options_from_database.php'.

For more info on Ajax(XMLHTTPRequest) you can look here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Comment: Thank you, that already helped. I have now set up an EventListener in javascript that shows an alert with the value of the selected option if the selection has changed.  Here is my file where the data is selected from the database: [query](http://ideone.com/ub0lBt).  That mysql query file is included in the Highcharts javascript code: [js](http://jsfiddle.net/23c28wtv/).  >WHERE unit=3  within the mysql query is basically what needs to be dynamically, but I don't know how to pass that variable to the mysql query?  The XMLHTTPRequest thing looks confusing to me, but i'll look further into it.

Comment: To pass the variable on to mysql you will most likely want to use prepared statements, seeing as it is just the easiest option. 

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

You can get the value in the php file by sending it as a GET parameter in the Ajax call, like so: request.send("get", "http://www.example.com/file.php?option=" + option, true), and get it in the php file with $_GET['option'].

Then just add a parameter to your javascript function that's drawing the chart and use it to pass whatever get's returned from the Ajax (request.responseText).

Comment: Thanks again, I think I'm slowly getting there. Is there any sort of debugging tool to analyze what values get sent and monitor the general process flow when for example changing the selection. I'm only working localy if that information is necessary.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the php file ?

Comment: I may have found the main mistake... Those html tags were in my php file too... I deleted them but it's still not working. Maybe I'm not inserting the response correctly? The php file now looks like this: [PHP file](http://ideone.com/EotkHn). Here is how I tried inserting the response to create the graph: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygeydtyd/)

Comment: Well, in the PHP file you are trying to use a variable 'unit' sent as a GET parameter, yet on the javascript file you are sending the ajax call as a POST (and also 'option' instead of 'unit').

The way you are sending the POST request is also invalid. To send data on a POST request you add the data when calling xmlhttp.send(), not attached to the url.

Comment: Oh god you are right. I have now changed the "POST" to "GET". And regarding the names, they are correct locally, I just changed them so they match the code you wrote earlier and forgot some. But I still have no idea why the grap doesn't get drawn. The chart is there, it is just empty.